# std::regex behaves differently between Mac OS and Linux

Tags: c++, regex, locale

I was struggling with unicode regex matching with C++ `std::regex`. I found that the `std::regex_search` function may return different values on Mac OS and Linux.

Here is the sample code.

```
#include "string"
#include "regex"
#include "iostream"
#include "locale"

void regex_test() {
  std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
  {
    std::wstring str(L"水");
    std::wregex re(L"\\w+", std::regex::collate);

    if (std::regex_search(str, re)) {
      std::cout << "match" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "failed to match" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  regex_test();
  return 0;
}
```

On Debian Stretch, the above code prints `match` while on Mac OS BigSur it prints `failed to match`.

I constructed the regex with `std::regex::collate` and set the locale in order to make the expression be locale sensitve. The expression `\w` should capture all unicode word characters. That is true on Linux, but not on Mac OS.

I suspected that it might be locale related, so I changed the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` on Mac OS, but it did not work.

Also I tried to change the compiler from GCC 6.3.0 to Clang 12 on Linux, and the result is still the same as GCC. On Mac OS I have not tried switching the compiler from Apple Clang to GCC.

Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Apple Clang is known for its quirks related to regex matching. If it is not a big trouble, try switching to GCC.

Comment: Handling of encoding of source file is compiler dependent, can you replace `水` by its equivalent `\u..` (or equivalent to make cpp file contains only ascii character)?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you for your reply, I will try to switch the compiler.

Comment: `en_US` is not really a locale in which I would expect consistent results for matching `L"水"`. `\w` is `[_[:alnum:]]`, which depends on the locale-specific `alnum` (alphanumeric).